# How do we find the logsumexp of all subsets (or some approximation to this)?

Tags: algorithm, statistics, logistic-regression, sampling, approximation

I have a set of numbers `n_1, n_2, ... n_k`. I need to find the sum (or mean, its the same) of the `logsumexp` of all possible subsets of this set of numbers. Is there a way to approximate this or compute it exactly?

Note, the `logsumexp` of `a, b, c` is `log(e_a + e_b + e_c)` (exp, followed by sum, followed by log)

Comment: It's an interesting question, but it's more likely to find an answer at https://math.stackexchange.com than here.

Comment: As @DavidEisenstat pointed out, if the empty set is not omitted, then the answer is zero.

Comment: Since a sum of logs is the same as a log of products, your problem is equivalent to calculating the log of the products of all the sums of possible subsets. For instance, for {a,b,c}, the sum over all subsets of logsumexp is equal to log((ea+eb+ec)(ea+eb)(ea+ec)(eb+ec)(ea)(eb)(ec)). So you're down to calculating the [product of sums of all subsets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2449756/product-of-sums-of-all-subsets) of {e^a, e^b, e^c}. Sadly that question didn't get any answer either, though it sounds like it could be answered with combinatorics.

Comment: How big is k exactly?

Comment: @Stef Thanks for the suggestion. K right now is about 50 but this could vary and go as high as 1000 (not beyond for now). I'll keep it here for a while, and if not solved, will go to math SO. Also thanks for the pointer to the other question. And yes, the empty subset is prohibited.

Answer (score 3):

I don’t know if this will be accurate enough, but log sum exp is sort of a smooth analog of max, so one possibility would be to sort so that n<sub>1</sub> ≥ n<sub>2</sub> ≥ … ≥ n<sub>k</sub> and return ∑<sub>i</sub> (2<sup>k−i</sup> / (2<sup>k</sup> − 1)) n<sub>i</sub>, which under-approximates the true mean by an error term between 0 and log k.

You could also use a sample mean of the log sum exp of {n<sub>i</sub>} ∪ (a random subset of {n<sub>i+1</sub>, n<sub>i+2</sub>, …, n<sub>k</sub>}) instead of n<sub>i</sub> in the sum. By using enough samples, you can make the approximation as good as you like (though obviously at some point it’s cheaper to evaluate with brute force).

(I’m assuming that the empty set is omitted.)

Answer (score 2):

On a different tack, here’s a deterministic scheme whose additive error is at most ε. As in my other answer, we sort n<sub>1</sub> ≥ … ≥ n<sub>k</sub>, define an approximation f(i) of the mean log sum exp over nonempty subsets where the minimum index is i, and evaluate ∑<sub>i</sub> (2<sup>k−i</sup> / (2<sup>k</sup> − 1)) f(i). If each f(i) is within ε, then so is the result.

Fix i and for 1 ≤ j ≤ k−i define d<sub>j</sub> = n<sub>i+j</sub> − n<sub>i</sub>. Note that d<sub>j</sub> ≤ 0. We define f(i) = n<sub>i</sub> + g(i) where g(i) will approximate the mean log one plus sum exp of subsets of {d<sub>j</sub> | j}.

I don’t want to write the next part formally since I believe that it will be harder to understand, so the idea is that with log sum exp being commutative and associative, we’re going to speed up the brute force algorithm that initializes the list of results as [0] and then, for each j, doubles the size of the list the list by appending the log sum exp with d<sub>j</sub> of each of its current elements. I claim that, if we round each intermediate result down to the nearest multiple of δ = ε/k, then the result will under-approximate at most ε. By switching from the list to its histogram, we can do each step in time proportional to the number of distinct entries. Finally, we set g(i) to the histogram average.

To analyze the running time, in the worst case, we have d<sub>j</sub> = 0 for all j, making the largest possible result log k. This means that the list can have at most (log k)/δ = ε<sup>−1</sup> k log k + 1 entries, making the total running time O(ε<sup>−1</sup> k<sup>3</sup> log k). (This can undoubtedly be improved slightly with a faster convolution algorithm and/or by rounding the d<sub>j</sub> and taking advantage.)